# Shopify Python Library - Set metafield value to blank

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to, using the Shopify Python library (which isn't that well documented), set a Metafield value that's currently a type single-line-text to either "" or Nil.

I've tried these solutions, and neither of them worked. My metafield definition will update to any other value I submit, but if I try submitting "" or None as the value, it will not change.

```
def add_order_metafield(tag, value):
    metafield = shopify.Metafield({
    'key': tag,
    'value': value,
    'type':'single_line_text_field',
    'namespace':'custom'
    })
    
    return metafield

#doesn't work
customer.add_metafield(add_order_metafield('date', ''))

#doesn't work
customer.add_metafield(add_order_metafield('date', None))

#works as intended
customer.add_metafield(add_order_metafield('date', "None"))
```

Any advice here would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Shopify's Metafield REST API comes with a notable limitation - empty strings cannot be saved.  When you add your `Date` metafield with an empty string it will not work. The same goes when you provide a value of `None` which is not a string.  All data that will be stored as metafield values should be a string regardless of the metafield's type.

With that, I would suggest you could solve this problem by,

1. Delete the metafield instead of updating its value to an empty string.
2. Represent empty string with an arbitrary placeholder.